# How do I give a TextField full width inside a coulmn

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have this layout:

```
OverlayEntry _createOverlayEntry() {
    RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
    var size = renderBox.size;
    var offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);

    return OverlayEntry(
        builder: (context) => Positioned(
          left: offset.dx,
          top: offset.dy + 38.0,
          width: size.width,
          child: Material(
            elevation: 6.0,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                    child: Icon(Icons.check_box_outline_blank),
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        height: 30.0,
                        width: 100.0,
                        color: Colors.green,
                        child: TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              hintText: "New To-Do"
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 30.0,
                        width: 100.0,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        child: TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              hintText: "Notes"
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ),
        )
    );
  }
```

Which gives me this ui:

[image: Faulty UI]

Now I would like to not set a hardcoded width and height for the TextField's and have them take just the height they need and all the remaning width the column offers. I tried with the following layout but it crashes with the message "RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded", so could you help explain how I can do this in Flutter please?

Comment: Have you tried using SizedBox Widget? Also Expanded is useless Widget in your case, try with SizedBox and MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/width percentage to set it custom width/height.

Comment: Why not using ``Row`` instead of ``Expanded``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things that are interesting about the approach you've taken here. Also, I'm going on the basis that you're trying to make the overlay be shown at the same place at the top of the screen each time, rather than over whatever you've tapped on, since that's shown [in the video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/05yu8tu23b2okv4/Flutter_animation.mp4?dl=0) you posted on another question.

The first interesting thing is that you've obtained a renderbox from the place where the `_createOverlayEntry` function is being called:

```
RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
var size = renderBox.size;
var offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
```

This means that you're actually using the offset of the renderbox of whatever is calling this function - which is likely not what you're trying to do. It's probably working just fine if you're putting this in the build of a widget that displays the entire screen, but it's something to consider and likely change.

The second thing you're doing is

```
top: offset.dy + 38.0,
```

which probably has a reason, but I'm generally a bit wary when I see arbitrary sizes in code for no particular reason. If you're trying to avoid the top bar, I'd recommend kToolbarHeight + ??, and if you're trying to avoid the status bar etc at the top of the screen you should use SafeArea.

And lastly, you probably don't need to be using positioned at all. If you use an alignment instead you can do this:

```dart
OverlayEntry(
  builder: (context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 38, left: 10, right: 10),
        child: Align(
          child: Material(
            elevation: 6.0,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                    child: Icon(Icons.check_box_outline_blank),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.green,
                          child: TextField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                hintText: "New To-Do"),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          child: TextField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: InputBorder.none, hintText: "Notes"),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

The two important parts of that are the column's mainAxisSize - if you don't set that it expands to take the entire screen; and the Expanded that is wrapping the column which makes sure that child of the row takes up all available space.

Also, you should remove the width from your container objects. I removed the height as well, but that is up to you.

Comment: Thank you very much @rmtmckenzie, this was more than I hoped for. I am new to Flutter and those hardcoded values was there because I did not know how to get the safe area and the kToolbarHeight and I posponed that to later, but now I know :) Any idea on how to aimate the position and size of the overlay also?

Comment: Actually I figured out the animation part :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify height and width of the containers (the column's children) and try:

**Width**

Setting `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,` for your column. Perhaps that might work for letting the width of the column stretch to that of the row it is in.

To set the width of the row, you can wrap your row in a container and use `width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,`. This gets the screen size width.

**Height**

You can wrap each of the columns children in `Expanded` and specify the flex they should have in the column's height.

To set the height of the column, you can wrap your row in a container and use `height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,`. This gets the screen size height. You may want to divide it with a value say 10 so `width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/10,`

There is a useful cheat sheet here: [Cheat Sheet](https://medium.com/jlouage/flutter-row-column-cheat-sheet-78c38d242041)

Comment: just setting CrossAxisAlignment wouldn't help as it would just align all its children within its extent, which would be set by the biggest child's size. You could set the width as you've stated but that is at best an ugly hack - you should almost never need to use mediaquery in a normal application.